# Not able to start SpringBoot app in debug mode, Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot

My application is a web application and I am able to hit endpoints successfully when run using "mvn spring-boot:run". Only problem is application shuts down when run in debug mode in intellij and not able to debug my application.

pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent body repository -->
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Output:

```
=========================
AUTO-CONFIGURATION REPORT
=========================

Positive matches:
-----------------
  .....

Negative matches:
-----------------
   ActiveMQAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: javax.jms.ConnectionFactory; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'getConnectionFactory' (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory', 'org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   ActiveMQConnectionFactoryConfiguration.PooledConnectionFactoryConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   ActiveMQXAConnectionFactoryConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager' (OnClassCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect', 'org.aspectj.lang.reflect.Advice' (OnClassCondition)

   ArtemisAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   BatchAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher', 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations' (OnClassCondition)

   CacheAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.cache.CacheManager'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   CacheAutoConfiguration.CacheManagerJpaDependencyConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean' (OnClassCondition)
         - Ancestor org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration did not match (ConditionEvaluationReport.AncestorsMatchedCondition)

   CaffeineCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine', 'org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   CassandraAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster' (OnClassCondition)

   CassandraDataAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster', 'org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminOperations' (OnClassCondition)

   CassandraRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.datastax.driver.core.Session', 'org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.CassandraRepository' (OnClassCondition)

   CloudAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.cloud.config.java.CloudScanConfiguration' (OnClassCondition)

   CouchbaseAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket', 'com.couchbase.client.java.Cluster' (OnClassCondition)

   CouchbaseCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket', 'com.couchbase.client.spring.cache.CouchbaseCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   CouchbaseDataAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket', 'org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.CouchbaseRepository' (OnClassCondition)

   CouchbaseRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket', 'org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.CouchbaseRepository' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' (OnClassCondition)

   DeviceDelegatingViewResolverAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.mobile.device.view.LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver' (OnClassCondition)

   DeviceResolverAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor', 'org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver' (OnClassCondition)

   DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet' (OnClassCondition)

   EhCacheCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'net.sf.ehcache.Cache', 'org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.elasticsearch.client.Client', 'org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.TransportClientFactoryBean', 'org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.NodeClientFactoryBean' (OnClassCondition)

   ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.elasticsearch.client.Client', 'org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate' (OnClassCondition)

   ElasticsearchRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.elasticsearch.client.Client', 'org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository' (OnClassCondition)

   EmbeddedLdapAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.unboundid.ldap.listener.InMemoryDirectoryServer' (OnClassCondition)

   EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.mongodb.Mongo', 'de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodStarter' (OnClassCondition)

   EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnWebApplication (required) not a web application (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'javax.servlet.Servlet', 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet' (OnClassCondition)

   FacebookAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.springframework.social.config.annotation.SocialConfigurerAdapter', 'org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   FallbackWebSecurityAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity' (OnClassCondition)

   FlywayAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.flywaydb.core.Flyway' (OnClassCondition)

   FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'freemarker.template.Configuration', 'org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'groovy.text.markup.MarkupTemplateEngine' (OnClassCondition)

   GsonAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.google.gson.Gson' (OnClassCondition)

   GsonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.google.gson.Gson' (OnClassCondition)

   GuavaCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder', 'org.springframework.cache.guava.GuavaCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.h2.server.web.WebServlet' (OnClassCondition)

   HazelcastAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance' (OnClassCondition)

   HazelcastCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance', 'com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   HazelcastJpaDependencyAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance', 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean' (OnClassCondition)

   HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean', 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' (OnClassCondition)

   HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter' (OnClassCondition)

   HypermediaAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.springframework.hateoas.Resource', 'org.springframework.plugin.core.Plugin' (OnClassCondition)

   InfinispanCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.infinispan.spring.provider.SpringEmbeddedCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   IntegrationAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration' (OnClassCondition)

   JCacheCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'javax.cache.Caching', 'org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.JodaDateTimeJacksonConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.joda.time.DateTime', 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.ser.DateTimeSerializer', 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.cfg.JacksonJodaDateFormat' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.ParameterNamesModuleConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paramnames.ParameterNamesModule' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverterConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper' (OnClassCondition)

   JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' (OnClassCondition)

   JerseyAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider', 'javax.servlet.ServletRegistration' (OnClassCondition)

   JestAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'io.searchbox.client.JestClient' (OnClassCondition)

   JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.JndiConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnJndi JNDI environment is not available (OnJndiCondition)

   JmsAutoConfiguration.JmsTemplateConfiguration#jmsTemplate:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'getJmsTemplate' (OnBeanCondition)

   JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - AnyNestedCondition 0 matched 2 did not; NestedCondition on JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.JndiOrPropertyCondition.Property @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.jms.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'; NestedCondition on JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.JndiOrPropertyCondition.Jndi @ConditionalOnJndi JNDI environment is not available (JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.JndiOrPropertyCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType' (OnClassCondition)

   JooqAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.jooq.DSLContext' (OnClassCondition)

   JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository' (OnClassCondition)

   JtaAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.transaction.Transaction' (OnClassCondition)

   KafkaAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate' (OnClassCondition)

   LdapAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.ldap.core.ContextSource' (OnClassCondition)

   LdapDataAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.LdapRepository' (OnClassCondition)

   LdapRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.LdapRepository' (OnClassCondition)

   LinkedInAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.springframework.social.config.annotation.SocialConfigurerAdapter', 'org.springframework.social.linkedin.connect.LinkedInConnectionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   LiquibaseAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase' (OnClassCondition)

   MailSenderAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage' (OnClassCondition)

   MailSenderValidatorAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.mail.test-connection) did not find property 'test-connection' (OnPropertyCondition)

   MessageSourceAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - ResourceBundle did not find bundle with basename messages (MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.ResourceBundleCondition)

   MongoAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.mongodb.MongoClient' (OnClassCondition)

   MongoDataAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.mongodb.Mongo', 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate' (OnClassCondition)

   MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.mongodb.Mongo', 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository' (OnClassCondition)

   MultipartAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'javax.servlet.Servlet', 'javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement' (OnClassCondition)

   MustacheAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.samskivert.mustache.Mustache' (OnClassCondition)

   Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   Neo4jRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession', 'org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository' (OnClassCondition)

   OAuth2AutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken' (OnClassCondition)

   ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration#buildProperties:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnResource did not find resource '${spring.info.build.location:classpath:META-INF/build-info.properties}' (OnResourceCondition)

   ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration#gitProperties:
      Did not match:
         - GitResource did not find git info at classpath:git.properties (ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration.GitResourceAvailableCondition)

   RabbitAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate', 'com.rabbitmq.client.Channel' (OnClassCondition)

   ReactorAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'reactor.spring.context.config.EnableReactor', 'reactor.Environment' (OnClassCondition)

   RedisAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection', 'org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisOperations', 'redis.clients.jedis.Jedis' (OnClassCondition)

   RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'redis.clients.jedis.Jedis', 'org.springframework.data.redis.repository.configuration.EnableRedisRepositories' (OnClassCondition)

   RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration' (OnClassCondition)

   SecurityAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager', 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter' (OnClassCondition)

   SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer', 'org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy' (OnClassCondition)

   SendGridAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.sendgrid.SendGrid' (OnClassCondition)

   ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnWebApplication (required) not a web application (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   SessionAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.session.Session' (OnClassCondition)

   SitePreferenceAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.springframework.mobile.device.site.SitePreferenceHandlerInterceptor', 'org.springframework.mobile.device.site.SitePreferenceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver' (OnClassCondition)

   SocialWebAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController', 'org.springframework.social.config.annotation.SocialConfigurerAdapter' (OnClassCondition)

   SolrAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient', 'org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient' (OnClassCondition)

   SolrRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient', 'org.springframework.data.solr.repository.SolrRepository' (OnClassCondition)

   SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.application.admin.enabled=true) did not find property 'enabled' (OnPropertyCondition)

   SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver' (OnClassCondition)

   ThymeleafAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine' (OnClassCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration.TransactionTemplateConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   TwitterAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.springframework.social.config.annotation.SocialConfigurerAdapter', 'org.springframework.social.twitter.connect.TwitterConnectionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'javax.servlet.Servlet', 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet' (OnClassCondition)

   WebServicesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet' (OnClassCondition)

   WebSocketAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'javax.servlet.Servlet', 'javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer' (OnClassCondition)

   WebSocketMessagingAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer' (OnClassCondition)

   XADataSourceAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager', 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType' (OnClassCondition)


Exclusions:
-----------
    None

Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebClientAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration



2017-03-09 09:09:34.931  INFO 3496 --- [           main] c.abc.jms.SpringbootJmsApplication  : Started SpringbootJmsApplication in 2.995 seconds (JVM running for 3.682)

68

2017-03-09 09:09:34.946  INFO 3496 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1f97cf0d: startup date [Thu Mar 09 09:09:32 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy

2017-03-09 09:09:34.946  INFO 3496 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 2147483647

2017-03-09 09:09:34.946  INFO 3496 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51873', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: The auto-configuration believes that your application isn't a web application. A non-web application typically doesn't start any threads to keep the JVM running so it exits. I can see that you have a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` so it should be a web application. It may not be because you've explicitly disabled it when creating your `SpringApplication` or a dependency has been corrupted so some classes are missing  from the classpath.

Comment: Just noticed the IDEA tag. IDEA has a problem with `provided` dependencies (currently commented out in your pom) as it omits them from the classpath. That's another possible cause.

Comment: It might be something to do with the `<relativePath/>` bit. That's non standard so remove it then see what happens.

Comment: same error I am getting even after removing <relativePath/>

Comment: What Run/Debug configuration type is used in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Run/Debug configurations: Spring Boot,
Main class: <application main class>,
Use classpath module: <selected respective module>,
JRE: <selected corresponding JRE>

Comment: @CrazyCoder I still could not fix this problem, let me know if you need more input from me. Thanks

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CrazyCoder It is working now, I had to delete the idea related settings files and upgrade to intelliJ 2016.3.5. It might happened due to renaming of the project folder I did. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can ignore these kind of errors and as Rohit mentioned, include the line in the application.properties and it after another compile or run it will tell you what is wrong with your code.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure=ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

Try delete the idea related settings files. It might happened due to renaming of the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Write this **line** in `application.properties` **file**:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure=ERROR
```

Comment: Question is irrelevant from log levels, please check the question again.